# Repeated sub-messages in protobuf-c

Tags: c, linux, serialization, protocol-buffers

Can somebody give me an example of packing\unpacking message with repeating sub-message in [protobuf-c](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/)?

Official documentation in [empty](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/wiki/Examples) on this matter.

Answer (score 2):

```
message B {
  required int64 i = 1;
};

message A {
  repeated B numbers = 1;
};

A a;
a.ParseFromString(<str>)
for (int i = 0; i < a.numbers_size(); ++i) {
  const B& b = a.numbers(i);
  printf("%d\n", b.i());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

proto:

```
message SubMsg {
  bytes value = 1;
}

message MainMsg {
  repeated SubMsg msgs = 1;
}
```

pack (do not forget to free memory (free(...)):

```
MainMsg mainMsg = { };
main_msg__init(&mainMsg);
SubMsg **subMsgs = calloc(LEN, sizeof(SubMsg*));
for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
    subMsgs[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(SubMsg));
    sub_msg__init(subMsgs[i]);
    subMsgs[i]->value.data = DATA;
    subMsgs[i]->value.len = DATALEN;
}
mainMsg.msgs = subMsgs;
mainMsg.n_msgs = LEN;
...
main_msg__pack(&mainMsg, BUFFER);
```

unpack (do not forget to free memory (..._free_unpacked(...)):

```
MainMsg* mainMsg = main_msg__unpack(nullptr, BUFFERLEN, BUFFER);
if (! mainMsg) {
    // error
    return;
}

SubMsg **subMsgs = mainMsg->msgs;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

proto:

```protobuf
message A {
  optional uint32 key = 1;
  optional uint64 value = 2;
}

message B {
  repeated A msg = 1;
}
```

if have optional XXX field, try to set has_XXX true;

```c
  B msg;  
  filebackup__heartbeat_content__init(&msg);
  A **subs = (A**)malloc(N * sizeof(A*));
  void *buf;                      
  unsigned len,i;                 
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    subs[i] = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A));
    filebackup__job_status__init(subs[i]);
    subs[i]->key = i + 1;
    subs[i]->has_key = 1;
    subs[i]->value = (i + 1) * 100;
    subs[i]->has_value = 1;
  }
  msg.msg = subs;
  msg.n_msg = N;
  len =  filebackup__heartbeat_content__get_packed_size(&msg);  
  buf = malloc(len);
  filebackup__heartbeat_content__pack(&msg, (uint8_t *)buf);
```

Answer (score -3):

"Reading A Message" section of Google's C++ tutorial has relevant sample code:
  http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/cpptutorial.html

Also, STL's for_each also appears to work OK (syntactic sugar, more-or-less):
    std::for_each(a.numbers().begin()
                 ,a.numbers().end()
                 ,[](const B& b) {
                    std::cout << b.i() << std::endl ;
                  }
                 ) ;

Comment: The question is about protobuf-c, not protobuf. And about C, not C++.